# SEO and H tag with custom attribute

Tags: html, seo

I would like to use custom attribute inside H tag
for example

```
<h3 mydata="1">header</h3>
```

Is this style is good for SEO ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This attribute will cause your HTML to stop validating because `mydata` is not a recognized attribute for the HTML DOCTYPE.

Instead, use `data-` attributes to store data. These are not parsed by search engines and have no effect on the SEO value of your page.

For more information, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure about SEO, but you should always do it in the format:

data-[attribute]

this is the prescribed "HTML5" way of doing custom data attributes and it works on non-html5 browsers. It also is useful when getting data using jQuery -> `$(selector).data()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store data in attributes then check-out HTML5's `data-attributes`: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-%2a)

You can safely use `data-attributes` as far as SEO is concerned.

Your attribute would look like this:

```
<h3 data-mydata="1">header</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

"mydata" wouldn't be valid HTML.  So no, not a good idea.

Use data-attributes instead.

Answer (score -3):

SHORT Answer YES, is valid SEO. SEO is all about search engines friendly URL's.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SEO

Anyways your HTML will not be valid. Use data-attribute instead, as suggested above.
If you're a picky HTML developer as I am, you can always validate your HTML using this tool:

http://validator.w3.org/