# cant grab value from div using attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery

check the html code bellow. i want to get value of `isred` on click by jquery. but problem with my code is that this returns undefined error in console.log. How can i fix it?

html:

```
<div value="123102302155" upc="076174942026" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon"><i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" class="fa fa-bullseye fa-lg" style="color:#82f520" isred="0" data-original-title="We successfully match supplier product, click to compare"></i></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnAmazon", function (e) {

var isred = $(this).attr("isred");
                console.log(isred);

});
```

Comment: Your `isred` attribute ís on the `<i>` tag, not the `div` with class `btnAmazon`.

Comment: ok but how to fix it then?

Comment: Please note that your HTML is **invalid**. You have a whole bunch of invalid attributes, which either are not HTML attributes (`upc`, `isred`), or don't exist on that element (`value` on `<div>`). Make these attributes `data-` attributes.

Comment: try this : var isred = $('i [isred]',this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *.btnAmazon* div doesn't have the *isred* attribute. If you want to add a custom attribute to your html, try to use `data-iserd="value"`. In the term of SEO it's not an standard attribute of html elements.
You can get the value with jquery like this:

```js
var isred = $(this).data("isred");
```

Also your query for getting access to that attribute is wrong. Try this:

```js
var isred = $('i', this).data("isred");
```

## Update

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".btnAmazon", function (e) {
    alert($('i',this).data("isred"));
  });
});
```

```css
.btnAmazon {

  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div value="123102302155" upc="076174942026" class="btn btn-default btnAmazon">
  <i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" class="fa fa-bullseye fa-lg" style="color:#82f520" data-isred="10" data-original-title="We successfully match supplier product, click to compare"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: *In the term of SEO it's not an standard attribute of html* What does this have to do with SEO?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649419/seo-and-h-tag-with-custom-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can get value from div using id
for example:-

`var demo = document.getElementById('demo').getAttribute('value');`